# Is a DelegateCommand the same as an "Attached Behavior"?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm, delegatecommand

I have been using the **DelegateCommand** found in the [MVVM Visual Studio template](http://wpf.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=WPF%20Model-View-ViewModel%20Toolkit) at CodePlex. This **works very nicely** for having Views be able to execute commands on their ViewModel.

I read somewhere that in MVVM "**attached behaviors**" should be used. As far as I can tell, "attached behaviors" are the same type of pattern as DelegateCommand but are used by **Silverlight** since it does not have commands.

Is this **correct**? Or are "attached behaviors" something different in kind and worth learning in addtiion to DelegateCommand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A DelegateCommand (or a RelayCommand, which is almost the same but accepts a parameter) is just a light-weight implementation of the ICommand interface that allows a ViewModel to expose commands easily.

Attached behaviors are a way to link an event to a command. For instance, most WPF controls don't have a Command property, so you can't normally define a command to react to their events. With attached behaviors, you can "bind" any event of any control to a command of your ViewModel.
Have a look at [Marlon Grech's implementation](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/), which seems the most flexible to me