# Handling many similar ICommand implementations?

Tags: mvvm, command

I am working with MVVM and encounter the following problem with the use of many similar commands.

I wanna make many buttons which is used to show the books of different categories.

The model is some data about a book, say,

```
class book 
{
    string name;
    string author;
    .....
    .....
    string category;
}
```

A list of book is stored. A GUI is used for the user to view the books with different categories. Therefore, buttons for each category is created. For example:

```
Buttons:

Comic
Social
Academic
Science
Leisure
Political
Cartoon
Gambling
Magazine
All
```

There are about 10 buttons that I have to created. (9 categories, 1 for viewing all)

In MVVM, each button has its own command. From that, there would be 10 commands in the ViewModel. However, the coding 9 of its are very similar with the only difference in the category.

So, I would like to ask if there is any suggestion/methods to make it more code-saving?

I do have an idea. That is to combine all the commands into one. However, this method required the View (Xaml) to pass a CommandParameter in each button to the one command in order to distinguish the different category. This will make the XAML more complex and increase coupling level with the ViewModels/Business logic.

So, would there are more concise way?

Comment: I don't understand your statement about using a CommandParameter... how does it make the XAML more complex or increase coupling? It's just an extra property on the button, and it makes your ViewModel much more concise.

Comment: I agree with Thomas Levesque, passing in the CommandParameter makes much more sense.  Your VM will be a lot lighter and the additional XAML isn't a concern.

Comment: I recommend refactoring your UI design.  Use a combo box to select the genre before hitting the button, or put each genre on a separate tab page (though you could share the body implementation for the pages themselves).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DelegateCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg431410%28v=pandp.39%29.aspx) from Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.dll and use CommandParameter

```
    <Button Command="{Binding bookCmd}"  CommandParameter="Comic">
    <Button Command="{Binding bookCmd}"  CommandParameter="Music">
    <Button Command="{Binding bookCmd}"  CommandParameter="News">


private DelegateCommand<string> _bookCmd;

_bookCmd= new DelegateCommand<string>(ExecuteBookCmd);

private void ExecuteBookCmd(string category)
{
 //Have fun
}
```

Comment: Because the DelegateCommand object is in Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.dll

Comment: Right but you can easily add it into your solution without PRISM (see [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924978/is-a-delegatecommand-the-same-as-an-attached-behavior)), anyway +1 for the good idea

Comment: The implementation of ICommand is trivial, so there's no need to use Prism.